# How differ debug/release mode, F5/ctrl+F5 mode

Tags: debugging, release

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Debug/Release difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367884/debug-release-difference)

I'm using visual studio 2010 as default settings.
It is very basic things, but I don't know exactly what they means, so I ask.
I read some articles about some kind of way of exceution, but I cannot understand cleary.

How F5 differ from ctrl+F5, and how debug mode differ from release mode.
And if there difference between each other in the view of performance?

Specific answers or links for article will be very helpful.

Thank you.

Comment: [This](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=what+is+the+difference+between+debug+and+release+mode) will give you plenty of good links.

Answer (score 0):

For the difference between Debug and Release mode, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367884/debug-release-difference).

Ctrl+F5 means "Build and run the project", and F5 means "Build and run the project under the debugger".  Both these commands are available in both Debug and Release mode, however, if you use F5 in Release mode, you'll have a less pleasant debugging experience and things might behave different than you expected. Running with the debugger attached does have *some* performance penalties,  so Ctrl+F5 will generally make your app run a bit faster.

Comment: Running with the debugger attached does have some performance penalties, so Ctrl+F5 will generally make your app run a bit faster. <- In my case, the difference of performance between them shown too much. Generally, the penalty can be serious? or it just depends on case by case.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3472671/does-net-code-run-slower-with-the-clr-debugger-attached-to-the-process Maybe this article is similar case

Comment: Depends case to case. You didn't mention what you are debugging, but if it's a managed C#/VB.NET app, right click your project in Solution Explorer, push Properties, select Debug, and make sure the "Enable unmanaged code debugging" checkbox is unchecked, as that can have the most dramatic effect on perf in my experience.